# Rails render partial with block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render, partial, ruby-block

I'm trying to re-use an html component that i've written that provides panel styling.  Something like:

```
  <div class="v-panel">
    <div class="v-panel-tr"></div>
    <h3>Some Title</h3>
    <div class="v-panel-c">
      .. content goes here
    </div>
    <div class="v-panel-b"><div class="v-panel-br"></div><div class="v-panel-bl"></div></div>
  </div>
```

So I see that render takes a block.  I figured then I could do something like this:

```
# /shared/_panel.html.erb
<div class="v-panel">
  <div class="v-panel-tr"></div>
  <h3><%= title %></h3>
  <div class="v-panel-c">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
  <div class="v-panel-b"><div class="v-panel-br"></div><div class="v-panel-bl"></div></div>
</div>
```

And I want to do something like:

```
#some html view
<%= render :partial => '/shared/panel', :locals =>{:title => "Some Title"} do %>
  <p>Here is some content to be rendered inside the panel</p>
<% end %>
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work with this error:

```
ActionView::TemplateError (/Users/bradrobertson/Repos/VeloUltralite/source/trunk/app/views/sessions/new.html.erb:1: , unexpected tRPAREN

old_output_buffer = output_buffer;;@output_buffer = '';  __in_erb_template=true ; @output_buffer.concat(( render :partial => '/shared/panel', :locals => {:title => "Welcome"} do ).to_s)
on line #1 of app/views/sessions/new.html.erb:
1: <%= render :partial => '/shared/panel', :locals => {:title => "Welcome"} do -%>
...
```

So it doesn't like the `=` obviously with a block, but if I remove it, then it just doesn't output anything.

Does anyone know how to do what I'm trying to achieve here?  I'd like to re-use this panel html in many places on my site.

Comment: The accepted answer is correct, but since Rails 5.0.0 this is possible without the `layout`-workaround, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials-to-simplify-views

Answer (score 242, accepted):

While both of those answers above work (well the example that tony links to anyway) I ended up finding the most succinct answer in that above post (comment by Kornelis Sietsma)

I guess `render :layout` does *exactly* what I was looking for:

```
# Some View
<%= render :layout => '/shared/panel', :locals => {:title => 'some title'} do %>
  <p>Here is some content</p>
<% end %>
```

combined with:

```
# /shared/_panel.html.erb
<div class="v-panel">
  <div class="v-panel-tr"></div>
  <h3><%= title -%></h3>
  <div class="v-panel-c">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: in Rails 3.2.2, I think you have to use `<%= %>` instead of `<% %>`, e.g. `<%= render :layout => '/shared/panel',`

Comment: you're right, this post makes no assumptions about the Rails version, I'm sure people can figure that one out.

Comment: like this one (solves my problem so +1), but is this good practice? won't there be some slowdown for some reason ? Maybe database triggers sooner than it suppose to because of another yield (don't have time to investigate that by-myself now, just wondering)

Comment: If the outside panel is a `form` (variable name `f`), you should use `yield f` instead.

Comment: Any way to know if a content has been yielded? In case of it's optional.

Comment: This seems to mess up the context for `I18n.t` >:(

Comment: Working with Rails `4.2.7` and got an error like `LocalJumpError` (no block given). Found out that when using `layout:` you have to name the hash for local parameters explicitly. e.g. `= render layout: 'mylaoyut', locals: {param1: 'Test'} do`

Comment: In Rails 5.0 there was a [change](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/5_0_release_notes.html#action-view-notable-changes) so this is general to all partials, not just layouts. You can change the first line of the calling code to: `<%= render '/shared/panel', title: 'some title' do %>`

Answer (score 34):

Here's an alternative based on previous answers.

Create your partial on `shared/_modal.html.erb`:

```
<div class="ui modal form">
  <i class="close icon"></i>
  <div class="header">
    <%= heading %>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <%= capture(&block) %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <div class="ui negative button">Cancel</div>
    <div class="ui positive button">Ok</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Define your method on `application_helper.rb`:

```
def modal_for(heading, &block)
  render(
    partial: 'shared/modal',
    locals: { heading: heading, block: block }
  )
end
```

Call it from any view:

```
<%= modal_for('My Title') do |t| %>
  <p>Here is some content to be rendered inside the partial</p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use the capture helper, and even inline in the render call :

```
<%= render 'my_partial',
           :locals => { :title => "Some Title" },
           :captured => capture { %>
    <p>Here is some content to be rendered inside the partial</p>
<% } %>
```

and in shared/panel:

```
<h3><%= title %></h3>
<div class="my-outer-wrapper">
  <%= captured %>
</div>
```

which will produce:

```
<h3>Some Title</h3>
<div class="my-outer-wrapper">
  <p>Here is some content to be rendered inside the partial</p>
</div>
```

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html

Comment: The inline pattern is nice for a partial needing multiple blocks.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the accepted answer this is what worked well for me using Rails 4.

We can render a panel as such:

```
= render_panel('Non Compliance Reports', type: 'primary') do
  %p your content goes here!
```

[image]

This requires a helper method and a shared view:

helper method (ui_helper.rb)

```
def render_panel(heading, options = {}, &block)
  options.reverse_merge!(type: 'default')
  options[:panel_classes] = ["panel-#{options[:type]}"]

  render layout: '/ui/panel', locals: { heading: heading, options: options } do
    capture(&block)
  end
end
```

View (/ui/panel.html.haml)

```
.panel{ class: options[:panel_classes] }
  .panel-heading= heading
  .panel-body
    = yield
```

Comment: This works in Rails 5.x too, I just needed to change `panel.html.haml` to `_panel.html.haml`

Answer (score 1):

I think it will work (just did quick dirty test) if you assign it to a variable first and then output it.

```
<% foo = render :partial => '/shared/panel', :locals =>{:title => "Some Title"} do %>
<p>Here is some content to be rendered inside the panel</p>
<% end %>
<%= foo %>
```