# Nested render partials in Rails3 with HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I am attempting the following

A HAML template with

```
#whitepanelMID
  #groups_view_scroller
    = render 'show' do
      = render 'short_field', locals: {label: 'Name:', value: @group.name}
      = render 'short_field', locals: {label: 'Description:', value: @group.description}
```

And the partials are _show.html.haml (note the use of **yield**)

```
%table#vert_table.no_borders{ cellpadding: '0', cellspacing: '0'}
  %tbody
    %tr
      %td{ cols: 2 } My table
    = yield
```

and _short_field.html.haml

```
%tr
  %th.vert_table_heads= label
  %td= value
```

The issue is that **yield** does not seem to work.

What's the proper way to use *block* in `render` in HAML?

**Update**

I found a *workaround*, which I don't like.

In the HAML template capture the output like

```
#whitepanelMID
  #groups_view_scroller
    - rows = capture_haml do
      = render partial: 'short_field', locals: {field_label: 'Name:', value: @group.name}
      = render partial: 'short_field', locals: {field_label: 'Site:', value: @group.site.description}
    = render partial: 'show', locals:{ content: rows}
    %br/
```

with the modified partial _show.html.haml with a `content` variable instead of `yield`

```
%table#vert_table.no_borders{ cellpadding: '0', cellspacing: '0'}
  %tbody
    %tr
      %td{ cols: 2 } My table
    != content
```

Happy to hear a better approach!

Comment: You may try taking a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951105/rails-render-partial-with-block

Comment: Thanks @vidaica, I used `= render layout:..` and does the trick!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just because the link provided by @vidaca is ERB, I want to post an equivalent for HAML.

Use `layout:` when using the wrapper template

```
#whitepanelMID
  #groups_view_scroller
    = render layout: 'show', locals:{ table_title: 'My table'}
      = render partial: 'short_field', locals: {field_label: 'Name:', value: @group.name}
      = render partial: 'short_field', locals: {field_label: 'Site:', value: @group.site.desccription }        
    %br/
```

and _show.html.haml partial (wrapper) like

```
%table#vert_table.no_borders{ cellpadding: '0', cellspacing: '0'}
  %tbody
    %tr
      %td{ cols: 2 }= table_title
    = yield
```

the wrapped partials (`short_field` in this case) work as-is.

Hope helps someone.