# Render :layout is searching for partial instead of layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, applicationcontroller

I understand this is a bad idea, but from what I've seen in ApplicationControllers, using:

```
render :layout => "something" ...
```

Should render using a layout located at `views/layouts/something.html.erb`

However, when I am making this call from inside of a view, it errors out with:

```
Missing partial my_controller_name/something with ... 
Searched in:
* "{path here}/app/views"
```

Which seems to me its looking for a partial, instead of a layout as I specified.  Does anyone know what is going on with that?

A sufficient example small enough to reproduce it:

```
<%= render :layout => 'something' do %>
  <div>Hello</div>
<% end %>
```

This is all under Rails vs 4.0.2

Comment: Yes, this somewhat is an instance of the XY problem.  My goal overall is something else completely, but just for this question I really am wondering why it is acting like it is.

Comment: can you post the code you are using in the view?

Comment: @Peege151 Sure, give me one minute...

Comment: Are you trying to render the entire view with that layout? Or just a part of the view?

Comment: @Jon just part of it

Comment: Have you looked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951105/rails-render-partial-with-block)?

Comment: I deleted my answer cause it was wrong... view this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951105/rails-render-partial-with-block

Comment: @Jon Thanks for that.  It's giving me an idea for how I would solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`render` works differently in controllers than it does in views. In controllers, it's primarily for rendering *action* templates, while in views, it's primarily for rendering *partial* templates. When you want to render a specific layout for an action, you have a few options, but all of them are in the controller.

If you want *every* action in a particular controller to use that layout, you can either specify `layout 'something'` in that controller (usually near the top) or for a `ApplesController`, you can create a new layout in `app/views/layouts/apples.html.erb` and this will automatically be used as the default layout for the `ApplesController`.

If you want just a single action in a controller to use that layout, you can use your `render layout: 'something'` inside of a controller action, where the action to render is implied to be the current action.

Links from the Rails docs:

- [Action Rendering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#options-for-render)
- [Partial Rendering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#naming-partials)
- [Nested Layouts](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-nested-layouts)

Comment: Accepted because it explicitly answers the question asked.  I'm working on building myself a solution for what I need to do, so no worries there, either =)