# Rails render partial with block and collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951105/rails-render-partial-with-block) but with a collection:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <%= render layout: 'today_items_list', locals: {items: @pos} do |po| %>
         <% @output_buffer = ActionView::OutputBuffer.new %>
        <%= link_to "##{po.id}", po %>
        <%= po.supplier.name %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

with partial/layout:

```
.tableless_cell.no_padding
  %h3.no_margin_vertical= title
  %ul.no_margin_vertical
    - for item in items
      %li= yield(item)
```

This renders as you expect but if I omit the weird '@output_buffer = ActionView::OutputBuffer.new', the buffer is not cleared and the list is rendered this way:

```
<li>
  <a href="/purchase_orders/4833">#4833</a>Supplier name
</li>
<li>
  <a href="/purchase_orders/4833">#4833</a>Supplier name
  <a href="/purchase_orders/4835">#4835</a>Supplier name 2
</li>
<li>
  <a href="/purchase_orders/4833">#4833</a>Supplier name
  <a href="/purchase_orders/4835">#4835</a>Supplier name 2
  <a href="/purchase_orders/4840">#4840</a>Supplier name 3
</li>
```

Never clearing the buffer between block invocation. What am I missing here?

(Riding on Rails 3.2.22)

Comment: This is new to me. Why are you loading `:layout`? Is this the actual layout or a partial? Okay I just looked it up. Very interesting, thank you, I learned something.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with Rails 3.2; with newer versions, you're able to pass [collections to partials](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections):

```
<%= render @pos, layout: 'today_items_list' %>

#app/views/pos/_today_items_list.html.erb
.tableless_cell.no_padding
   %h3.no_margin_vertical= title
     %ul.no_margin_vertical
        <%= yield %>

#app/views/post/_po.html.erb
<%= link_to "##{po.id}", po %>
<%= po.supplier.name %>
```

You can [read more about collections etc (I presume for Rails 4+) here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html#class-ActionView::PartialRenderer-label-Rendering+partials+with+layouts).

Comment: Thanks Rich. You can already do this with Rails 3.2. I'm aware that you can have another partial but I like to see the code directly in the same file.

Comment: Okay mate, do you want me to delete the answer if it doesn't help?