# unexpected error using yield in haml nesting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, yield

Server Log:

```
Processing by GamesController#index as HTML
  Rendered games/index.haml within layouts/games (0.1ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Truncated layout is:

```
  %body
    = render partial: '/layouts/gamescreen/viewport'
      = yield
```

Partial *games.haml* content is a single Haml div:

```
  #viewport
```

Yield'ed view is:

```
  Hi!
```

Resulted error message:

```
  /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views/layouts/games.haml:12: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the [answer for this question "Rails render partial with block"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2952056/1166161) holds the solution.

In your layout you'd use

```
= render layout: '/layouts/gamescreen/viewport' do 
  Hi!
```

And in your `layouts/gamescreen/viewport` partial, you'd have

```
= yield
```